# Where is better to store the data in the custom Kubernetes resource

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have a question about where is better to store the data in the custom Kubernetes resource.
As I know, I can store data (maybe a big size data) in the **annotation**, or store in the **status** of the resource.
So where is better for performance or better to store? If I store a big data in annotation or status, will it take more space in etcd?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what kind of data are you referring to?

Comment: Just another custom resource spec which is the parent(owner) of this resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the locations you've suggested seem like the wrong place to store large pieces of data.
For configuration related data that needs to be shared between a few resources, use a [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).
If the data is specific to each pod, use [volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Thanks Yaron! it is not a very large data, just another normal custom resource, I want to keep it into another custom resource, so I would like to know where (annotation or status) is better.